# Getting the error "cannot add foreign key constraint" in my last stament in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, toad

2(a)

(i)

```
 Create table staffs(Staff_Id integer not null primary key,
 Name varchar(255),
 Staff_Type varchar(255),
 Session_Id integer not null); 

 select * from staffs;
```

(ii)

```
Create table Customers(Customer_Name Varchar(255) primary key);



 select * from customers
```

(iii)

```
Create table Freelancers (Freelancer_Name varchar(255) primary key,
 Freelancer_Type Varchar(255));

select * from freelancers;
```

(iv)

```
Create table Studio(Record_studio Integer not null primary key);




select * from studio;
```

(v)

```
drop table sessions;




Create table Sessions(Session_No integer not null primary key,
 Session_Type varchar(255),
 Session_Title varchar(255),
 Session_Date varchar(255),
 Customer_Name varchar(255),
 Staff_Id integer,
 Freelancer_Name varchar(255),
 Record_Studio integer); 



ALTER TABLE Sessions
ADD FOREIGN KEY 
(Customer_Name) REFERENCES Customers(Customer_Name);

ALTER TABLE Sessions
ADD FOREIGN KEY 
(Staff_Id) REFERENCES Staffs(Staff_Id);

ALTER TABLE Sessions
ADD FOREIGN KEY 
(Freelancer_name) REFERENCES Freelancers(Freelancer_Name);

ALTER TABLE Sessions
ADD FOREIGN KEY 
(Record_Studio)REFERENCES Studio(Record_Studio);



select * from Sessions;
```

---

Below statement is giving me the error "cannot add foreign key constraint"

Link to the error mysql error code
 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_cannot_add_foreign

???????????????????????????????????????????????

```
ALTER TABLE Staffs
ADD FOREIGN KEY (Session_Id) REFERENCES Sessions(Sessions_No);
```

????????????????????????????????????????????????

---

Comment: A typo: your query reads Sessions_No instead of Session_No

Comment: your question formatting is not good

Answer (score 0):

Ok i figured that is was a typo error.

ALTER TABLE Staffs ADD FOREIGN KEY (Session_Id) REFERENCES Sessions(Sessions_No)

Answer

ALTER TABLE Staffs ADD FOREIGN KEY (Session_Id) REFERENCES Sessions(Session_No)